# MVC Core 2.0 EF Core SqlException: New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0

There are a lot of threads for this issue but most seem to come up in the context of someone trying to loop and save on an IQueryable instead of an IList, which is not what I'm doing.

I am having an issue with a context being passed between my controller and my Repository. I am having this issue elsewhere in my app, but an easy way to illustrate and recreate this is below.

First, I'm setting up my DbContext in Startup.cs as a service.

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
      options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Then, I have a controller that it gets injected to. The first two saves work fine when I use the context straight from the controller, but when I use it from the repo, it errors out with the exception in the title. Note that it only errors if I save a record in the controller before I try to save it in my repo.

```
 private ApplicationDbContext _context;
 private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

 private ApplicationUser _user
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result;
        }
    }

 public InitiativesController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    // GET: Initiatives
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        Initiative i2 = new Initiative();
        i2.Id = 2;
        i2.InitiativeName = "testname";
        _context.Update(i2);
        _context.SaveChanges(); // Works fine

        var i4 = _context.Initiatives.SingleOrDefault(init => init.Id == 2);
        i4.InitiativeName = "blep";
        _context.Update(i4);
        _context.SaveChanges(); // Works fine


        InitiativeRepository initiativeRepository = new InitiativeRepository(_context, _user);

        var i= initiativeRepository.Get(2);
        i.InitiativeName = "blah";
        initiativeRepository.Update(i); //Throws exception

        var initiatives = initiativeRepository.GetAll();
        return View(initiatives);
    }
```

Here is the repository class:

```
public class InitiativeRepository
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private ApplicationUser _user;

    public InitiativeRepository(ApplicationDbContext context, ApplicationUser user)
    {
        _context = context;
        _user = user;
    }

    public Initiative Get(int id, bool eagerLoad = false)
    {
        if (!eagerLoad)
        {
            return _context.Initiatives.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
        }
        else
        {
            return _context.Initiatives.Include(i => i.Tasks).ThenInclude(t => t.ActionItems).
                SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == id);
        }
    }

    public List<Initiative> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Initiatives.ToList();
    }

    public Initiative Update(Initiative Entity)
    {
        _context.Update(Entity);
        _context.SaveChanges(); // This line causes the exception.
        return Entity;
    }

}
```

This should be the entry point for any DB writing, however, I am using ASP.NET identity and am autologged in for this session, so I'm not sure if it might be impacting this as well.

Comment: Are you sure those first two Updates() are actually doing anything? The only explanation I can think of is that those are effectively NO-OPs (because the data in DB is already what you're trying to set it to), but the 3rd one is actually attempting to make a change, but it can't because you have active result set opened from outside this code.

Comment: Yup, I can change the string literals and I can see the updates reflected in the DB. I think you are correct in that I have an active result set opened outside this code. I closed VS2017 and reopened, and this code runs fine now, but at a certain point in my app, another area bombs with the same error message. I must be opening some result set without closing it, but I can't figure out where. I also don't understand why this would be intermittent like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe in dependency injection at all times do to something like this happening.  While it is annoying you may be better served either doing everything in your repo or else closing and disposing of your context via:

```
using(var context = new context("yourContext"))
{
   //dowork
   context.SaveChanges();  
}
```

What may be happening even though it should not be, and this is just a guess.  Is that the injection is catching the wrong state of the context when it is passed in.  You could just do a dependency injection in your constructor of the repo instead and then just do everything with CRUD operations directly in the repo.

```
private InitiativeRepository _initiativeRepository;


public InitiativesController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
    _context = context;
    _userManager = userManager;
    _initiativeRepository = new InitiativeRepository(_context, _user);

}
```

I do a pattern like above currently with .NET Core 2 Web Api with controllers.  I know any time I have kept a context and not closed it and then mixed that context with another state that uses it, I get in trouble.  I also had it beat into me not to use dependency injection for contexts so it is interesting with the new .NET Core stuff they are making that the default.  It probably will work great till larger databases and multi user apps have a lot of work being done.